# How to build Android apps for tablet sized screens?

Tags: android, resolution, tablet

I've set up NetBeans to run my app on my Asus Transformet tablet, however, it runs using the size of a phone screen, and then gets stretched over the screen. How do I fix it so it uses the tablets resolution?

Comment: You might want to read this: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have custom layouts depending on the size of the screen.  For example if you have a xlarge screen you can create the layout folder 'layout-xlarge' and 'layout-xlarge-land'.  In these folders you can put the layouts (with the same name and variable names) but change the layout as needed.

I'd suggest reading this as well:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Ah, thanks! just had to add the size to the supports-screens section in the manifest too.

Comment: This is also a good doc to read: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
          android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Use targetSDK = 11 to target for the tablets. Your UI will automatically scale to the tablet size. Use minSdKVersion = 4, if your app should run on phones with Android 1.6 or more

For more API levels, you can check this out, http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html